# Is it possible that a convex cone and its closure both induce vector lattices?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convex-geometry, lattices, examples

Given a convex cone $P\subset X$ where $X$ is a $K$-vector space, $K=\mathbb{R}\text{ or }\mathbb{C}$ is a field.

Suppose that $P$ satisfies positive element stipulations.

(1) $X=P-P$.

(2) $P\cap-P=\{0\}$.

Then we can define a partial ordering on $X$ by defining $x\geq_P y\Leftrightarrow x-y\in P$ for $\forall x,y\in X$.

Now we construct a norm $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert$  on this space $X$, if the closure w.r.t. norm induced topology $P\subsetneqq\bar{P}\subset X$ also satisfies positive element stipulations, is there an example that $\left(X,\geq_{P}\right)$ and $\left(X,\geq_{\bar{P}}\right)$ are both vector lattices?